# Java Async Processing

Tags: java, architecture, asynchronous, hazelcast

I am currently developing a system that uses allot of async processing. The transfer of information is done using Queues. So one process will put info in the Queue (and terminate) and another will pick it up and process it. My implementation leaves me facing a number of challenges and I am interested in what everyone's approach is to these problems (in terms of architecture as well as libraries).

Let me paint the picture. Lets say you have three processes:

```
Process A -----> Process B
                      |
Process C <-----------|
```

So **Process A** puts a message in a queue and ends, **Process B** picks up the message, processes it and puts it in a "return" queue. **Process C** picks up the message and processes it.

1. How does one handle **Process B** not listening or processing messages off the Queue? Is there some JMS type method that prevents a Producer from submitting a message when the Consumer is not active? So **Process A** will submit but throw an exception.
2. Lets say **Process C** has to get a reply with in X minutes, but **Process B** has stopped (for any reason), is there some mechanism that enforces a timeout on a Queue? So guaranteed reply within X minutes which would kick off **Process C**.

Can all of these matters be handled using a dead letter Queue of some sort? Should I maybe be doing this all manually with timers and check. I have mentioned JMS but I am open to anything, in fact I am using Hazelcast for the Queues.

Please note this is more of a architectural question, in terms of available java technologies and methods, and I do feel this is a proper question.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at Akka? Actors sound like the ideal solution for your case. Although akka is popular in scala, it also works in java.

Comment: I will look into Akka. Thanks to everyone for their solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, The simplest solution is to use an ExecutorService, or a solution based on an executor service.  This supports a queue of work, scheduled tasks (for timeouts).

It can also work in a single process. (I believe Hazelcast supports distributed ExecutorService)

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the type of questions you're asking are "smells" that queues and async processing may not be the best tools for your situation.

1) That defeats a purpose of a queue. Sounds like you need a synchronous request-response process.

2) Process C is not getting a reply generally speaking. It's getting a message from a queue. If there is a message in the queue and the Process C is ready then it will get it. Process C could decide that the message is stale once it gets it, for example.

Answer (score 2):

I think your first question has already been answered adequately by the other posters.

On your second question, what you are trying to do may be possible depending on the messaging engine used by your application. I know this works with IBM MQ. I have seen this being done using the **WebSphere MQ Classes for Java** but not JMS. The way it works is that when **Process A** puts a message on a queue, it specifies the time it will wait for a response message. If **Process A** fails to receive a response message within the specified time, the system throws an appropriate exception.

I do not think there is a standard way in JMS to handle request/response timeouts the way you want so you may have to use platform specific classes like WebSphere MQ Classes for Java.

Answer (score 1):

Well, kind of the point of queues is to keep things pretty isolated.

If you're not stuck on any particular tech, you could use a database for your queues.

But first, a simple mechanism to ensure two processes are coordinated is to use a socket. If practical, simply have process B create an open socket listener on some well know port, and process A will connect to that socket, and monitor it. If process B ever goes away, process A can tell because their socket gets shutdown, and it can use that as an alert of problems with process B.

For the B -> C problem, have a db table:

```
create table queue (
    id integer,
    payload varchar(100), // or whatever you can use to indicate a payload
    status varchar(1),
    updated timestamp
)
```

Then, Process A puts its entry on the queue, with the current time and a status of "B". B, listens on the queue:

```
select * from queue where status = 'B' order by updated
```

When B is done, it updates the queue to set the status to "C".

Meanwhile, "C" is polling the DB with:

```
select * from queue where status = 'C' 
    or (status = 'B' and updated < (now - threshold) order by updated
```

(with the threshold being however long you want things to rot on the queue).

Finally, C updates the queue row to 'D' for done, or deletes it, or whatever you like.

The dark side is there is a bit of a race condition here where C might try and grab an entry while B is just starting up. You can probably get through that with a strict isolation level, and some locking. Something as simply as:

```
select * from queue where status = 'C' 
    or (status = 'B' and updated < (now - threshold) order by updated 
FOR UPDATE
```

Also use FOR UPDATE for B's select. This way whoever win the select race will get an exclusive lock on the row.

This will get you pretty far down the road in terms of actual functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You are expecting the semantics of synchronous processing with async (messaging) setup which is not possible. I have worked on WebSphere MQ and normally when the consumer dies, the messages are kept in the queue forever (unless you set the expiry). Once the queue reaches its depth, the subsequent messages are moved to the dead letter queue.

Answer (score 1):

I've used a similar approach to create a queuing and processing system for video transcoding jobs.  Basically the way it worked was:

1. `Process A` posts a "schedule" message to `Arbiter Q`, which adds the job into its "waiting" queue.
2. `Process B` requests the next job from `Arbiter Q`, which removes the next item in its "waiting" queue (subject to some custom scheduling logic to ensure that a single user couldn't flood transcode requests and prevent other users from being able to transcode videos) and inserts it into its "processing" set before returning the job back to `Process B`.  The job is timestamped when it goes into the "processing" set.
3. `Process B` completes the job and posts a "complete" message to `Arbiter Q`, which removes the job from the "processing" set and then modifies some state so that `Process C` knows the job completed.
4. `Arbiter Q` periodically inspects the jobs in its "processing" set, and times out any that have been running for an unusually long amount of time.  `Process A` is then free to attempt to queue up the same job again, if it wants.

This was implemented using JMX (JMS would have been much more appropriate, but I digress).  `Process A` was simply the servlet thread which responded to a user-initiated transcode request.  `Arbiter Q` was an MBean singleton (persisted/replicated across all the nodes in a cluster of servers) that received "schedule" and "complete" messages.  Its internally managed "queues" were simply `List` instances, and when a job completed it modified a value in the application's database to refer to the URL of the transcoded video file.  `Process B` was the transcoding thread.  Its job was simply to request a job, transcode it, and then report back when it finished.  Over and over again until the end of time.  `Process C` was another user/servlet thread.  It would see that the URL was available, and present the download link to the user.

In such a case, if `Process B` were to die then the jobs would sit in the "waiting" queue forever.  In practice, however, that never happened.  If your `Process B` is not running/doing what it is supposed to do then I think that suggests a problem in your deployment/configuration/implementation of `Process B` more than it does a problem in your overall approach.